# Play!Framework how to view details on threads?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm running Play Framework 2.0.  I'm trying to see the threads information.

I was checking online and saw that some people were running "play status" to see this info.

Where do you run this?  It seems I am not able to run this or was that in previous version of Play?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a play 1.x feature that never got ported to 2.x.

To get threads information for a play app (or any JVM app) I would use VisualVM which is shipped with the JDK.